# How to send a parameter and update an element using ajax in cakephp 2.x

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have an input field "#PostTitle" in which the user can enter a URL.

I want to send the user's input (upon change or upon exiting the field) to an action in my Posts controller which returns an array. Without CakePHP I think this would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#PostTitle').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '/posts/setPostImages',  
           data: $(this).serialize(),
           success: function(data){
                do something;
           },
           error: function(message){
                console.debug(message);
           }
      });
 return false;
 });
});
```

The action in the Posts controller sets an array of links called $imageArray
 (I CURL the page and return an array of all the images on that page, if it's of any interest).

Then, after I make the request, I would like to update an element which depends the contents of that array. The element contains the following code:

```
<div id="slider-wrap" class="boxframe">
    <div class="coda-slider" id="slider-id">
     <?php foreach ($imageArray as $image): ?>
        <div class="crop">
        <?php echo $this->Html->image($image); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:** If I try this, the action isn't called at all:

```
echo $this->Js->link('update',
      array('action' => 'setPostImages'),
      array(
         'update' => '#selectImage',
         'data' => 'www.stackoverflow.com',
         'async' => true,    
         'dataExpression'=>true,
         'method' => 'POST'
      )
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate this JS with CakePHP, take a look at [JsHelper's event method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper%3a%3aevent) and [request method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper%3a%3arequest)

The action the POST request hits should render your element and respond with HTML. JsHelper::request will then replace the contents of the element specified by the `update` param with your HTML.

Personally, I find it fairly obtuse to generate Javascript with a PHP framework. It quickly becomes difficult to do what you want. If you have even a moderate amount of Javascript, I recommend just writing it directly (you already seem to know how to do this!).

Your edit refers to a possibly different issue. What kind of Javascript errors are you getting in your browser's console when you click the link generated by that snippet?

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the tipps. I'm trying to get this to work from within Javascript now, but I'm still not getting the hang of it. Could you take a look please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299196/ajax-keeps-returning-the-calling-page