# Ajax keeps returning the calling page

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I have this ajax request which is being called whenever I change an input field:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#PostTitle').change(function(){
        var inputstring=$("#PostTitle").val();
        submitData(inputstring);
    });
});

function submitData(inputstring){
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/myWebsite/posts/set_post_images',
        data: inputstring,
        dataType: "text",
        success:function(data){
            $("#selectImage").replaceWith($('#selectImage', $(data)));
        },
        error:function(){
            $('#selectImage').html("You failed misserably.");
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });
}
```

The above code is in the add.ctp file (a View for the Posts Controller). The called function set_post_images is in the Posts Controller itself and looks like this:

```
public function set_post_images($url = null) {
    if($url!=null){
        $this->set('imageArray', $this->getImages($url));
    } else {
        $this->set('imageArray', array("/img/someImage.png"));
    }
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
         $this->autoRender = false;
         $this->layout = 'ajax';
         $this->render('/elements/selectImageElement');
    }
    return;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the existing element from the selectImage div replaced by the new element. The problem is, ajax keeps returning the entire contents of the add.ctp file (the file from which the request is called).

What could be the cause of this and how can I fix it?

**Edit**: **Solved**

$this->Auth->allow(array('set_post_images')); wasn't set, so the response was returning the entire page. After fixing that the action could be spoken to.

Also, in the controller, the variable is not accessed via $url but via $this->data['url'].

Happy coding!

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to see what the request looks like. The request body seems irrelevant here, but the URL may be important. I know you've set the URL in your code, but best to see where the browser is actually requesting. From there, step through your action's logic. Is `isAjax()` true? Recent Cake would have a statement like `$this->request->is('ajax')` without using RequestHandler. Finally, check the server response in the browser. Is the server returning the whole `add.ctp` view, or is it your `replaceWith` code making a mistake?

Comment: Hello Ben. The Request looks okay to me:
`Request URL:http://localhost/CheckMates/posts/set_post_images
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK`

The request header contains this, which also seems okay:
`Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/CheckMates/posts/add`

I'm not sure how to verify the controller action itself, since debugging doesn't show anything at all (could be normal in this case?).  

The response is the entire add.ctp, the browser dev tools shows it as such and if I output the data with alert(data) it displays the entire code...

Comment: Oh, also, I replaced the RequestHandler with your code before checking the request.

Comment: Remove the AJAX check. Get that action working correctly when you look at it with your browser. Debugging with `alert()` or inspecting response bodies is not fun. When you're all set, hook it back up to the frontend with AJAX.

Comment: Okay, I feel a bit silly now... Two things were off in my code.

The most important one was that $this->Auth->allow didn't contain the set_post_images action, thus it couldn't be accessed at all. I noticed this after your comment, when I tried to access the action manually. The second this is I wasn't even using the parameter passed by the request. Now I've replaced $url with $this->data['url'] in my Controller Action and everything is working fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this->Auth->allow(array('set_post_images')); wasn't set, so the response was returning the entire page. After fixing that the action could be spoken to.

Also, in the controller, the variable is not accessed via $url but via $this->data['url'].

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following code,

```
public function set_post_images($url = null) {
    if($url!=null){
        $this->set('imageArray', $this->getImages($url));
    } else {
        $this->set('imageArray', array("/img/someImage.png"));
    }
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
         $this->autoRender = false;
         $this->layout = 'ajax';
         $this->render('/elements/selectImageElement');
    }
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please insert the returns of set_post_images to a div with id 'returned-images' then change your ajax code to this

```
function submitData(inputstring){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/myWebsite/posts/set_post_images',
    data: inputstring,
    dataType: "text",
    success:function(data){
        var images = data.find('#returned-images');
        var getResults=images.html();
        $("#selectImage").html(getResults);
    },
    error:function(){
        $('#selectImage').html("You failed misserably.");
    },
    timeout: 5000
});
```

}

Cheers